# "UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte" error when attempting to remove nvidia-304 package

Tags: package-management, nvidia, dpkg

I'm trying to remove package `nvidia-304` from my system (Ubuntu 14.04) but I'm getting this error:

```python
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 283298 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing nvidia-304 (304.117-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing all DKMS Modules
Error! There are no instances of module: nvidia-304
304.117 located in the DKMS tree.
Done.
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_GL.conf (x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/i386-linux-gnu_GL.conf (i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf) in auto mode
INFO:Disable nvidia-304
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/dell_latitude
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/lenovo_thinkpad
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/put_your_quirks_here
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/quirks-handler", line 65, in <module>
    operation_status = main(options)
  File "/usr/bin/quirks-handler", line 48, in main
    quirks = Quirks.quirkapplier.QuirkChecker(options.package_disable, path=quirks_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/Quirks/quirkapplier.py", line 38, in __init__
    self._system_info = self.get_system_info()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/Quirks/quirkapplier.py", line 64, in get_system_info
    return quirk_info.get_dmi_info()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/Quirks/quirkinfo.py", line 46, in get_dmi_info
    'class', 'dmi', 'id', item)).read().strip()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/codecs.py", line 313, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte
dpkg: error processing package nvidia-304 (--purge):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.3) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nvidia-304
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I want to remove it because

1. it's not used
2. attempting to install `fslint` fails due to `nvidia-304` package not being fully configured

All problems only started after upgrading from version 13.10 to 14.04 LTS.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: I've tried dpkg-reconfigure but it gives me just `nvidia-304 is broken or not fully installed`

Comment: what's the output of `hexdump /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/put_your_quirks_here`?

Comment: python seems to think that it has at least one `0xff` byte at beginning.

Comment: it looks more like some problem with python than with quirks

Answer (score 1):

The exact error is here:

```python
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte
```

You can't fix it in the sense of middling with the code and fix it. Is a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-drivers-common/+bug/1320868) which IMO will be quite easy to fix from the developer perspective (modify the encoding of the file). Now, the only way to remove the package is forcefully, **which I don't recommend for any case**.

I see that `/usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/put_your_quirks_here` seems to be a dummy file, and probably the cause of problems. You should check with `file /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/*` whenever there files are not UTF-8, like this:

```
$ file /mnt/usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/*
/mnt/usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/dell_latitude:        ASCII text
/mnt/usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/lenovo_thinkpad:      ASCII text
/mnt/usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/put_your_quirks_here: empty
```

If those files are not `ASCII text`, consider removing them all, then try to remove the package again.

Comment: My output of file... is exactly the same. I also tried to check hexdump of 'put_your_quirks_here' and output was empty too